# How to index using elasticsearch on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, indexing, mongoid, elasticsearch

I am trying to install elasticsearch on Ubuntu 12.04 to work with tire and mongodb, I used the following code to do the installation and everything seems to be working fine:

```
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.90.2.deb
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-0.90.2.deb
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Elasticsearch appears to have installed to usr/share/elasticsearch but no config/elasticsearch.yml file was created during installation, where can i create/get this file and index the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands for starting and stopping elastic search:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
sudo service elasticsearch stop
```

Comment: It should be "elasticsearch" (no space).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this query just run it in terminal(project directory)

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS=Model_Name FORCE=true
```

Give your Model Name where you have implemented tire

let me know your feedback

Answer (score -1):

Answers are found in elasticsearch guide

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation/

> After downloading the latest release and extracting it, elasticsearch
>   can be started using:
>
> $ bin/elasticsearch
>
> Under *nix system, the command will start the process in the
>   background. To run it in the foreground, add the -f switch to it:
>
> $ bin/elasticsearch -f
>
> ElasticSearch is built using Java, and requires at least Java 6 in
>   order to run. The version of Java that will be used can be set by
>   setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: when i run bin/elasticsearch, I get "-bash: bin/elasticsearch: No such file or directory", i can't work out what i'm doing wrong

Comment: When i run "sudo service elasticsearch start" I get " * Starting ElasticSearch Server                                         [ OK ]", so it seems to be running

Comment: Ok good :) So if my answer helped don't forget to validate it

Comment: Your answer didn't help unfortunately. My question was how can I index the data

Comment: My bad, try seeing this rails cast you'll find your answer there http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1 also check if this file exists by typing `ls /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.18.5/config/elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: the file "/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.18.5/config/elasticsearch.yml" does not exist, usr/share/elasticsearch does exist, but there is no config/elasticsearch.yml file, i'm not sure why it wasn't created

Comment: Ok I think I found it in this guide http://xenforo.com/community/threads/how-to-basic-elasticsearch-installation-debian-ubuntu.26163/ you need to download the yml file. Let me know

Comment: ah, I finally found the elasticsearch.yml file in etc/elasticsearch

Do i copy over the same config that I used for localhost on my mac os x?

Comment: Found your solution finaly?